# How I compare different parameters among the values of a single array in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have an array that can have an undetermined number of scripts and I am trying to compare those scripts one by one. Something like this:

```
script1-script2
script1-script3
script1-script4
script2-script3
script2-script4
script3-script4
and so on...
```

The parameters that I want to compare among the scripts are:

- number of total lines
- number of blank lines
- number of commented lines
- number of comments
- number of times that the commands if, case, for and while are used
- number of variable used and their names (this parameter I am still
  trying how to chech it).

Until now I have been using for loops through my array getting these parameters calculated for each script individually. But I am not being able to find a way to compare the parameters of each script in the way that I said.

The structure that I am using is this:

```
echo "NUMBER OF TOTAL LINES";
for i in "${script[@]}"
do
cat $i | wc -l
done
echo "NUMBER OF COMMENTS";
for i in "${script[@]}"
do
grep -o '#' $i | wc -l
done 
echo "NUMBER OF IF COMMANDS"
for i in "${script[@]}"
do
grep -o 'if' $i | wc -l
done
```

And the output that I got is:

```
NUMBER OF TOTAL LINES
12
19
70
NUMBER OF COMMENTS
4
5
8
NUMBER OF IF COMMANDS
3
0
2
```

The ouput that I would need is (the array can have an undetermined number of scripts):

```
the script1 has 12 lines and the script2 has 19 lines
the script1 has 12 lines and the script3 has 70 lines
the script2 has 19 lines and the script3 has 70 lines

the script1 has 4 comments and the script2 has 5 comments
the script1 has 4 comments and the script3 has 8 comments
the script2 has 5 comments and the script3 has 8 comments

the script1 has 3 if commands and the script2 has 0 if commands
the script1 has 3 if commands and the script3 has 2 if commands
the script2 has 0 if commands and the script3 has 2 if commands
```

Comment: please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your question; in particular ... sample data, the (incorrect) output you're currently generating, and the desired (correct) output

Comment: Thank you, I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, almost but not quite, feel free to tweak the code to your own hearts content.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

funct() {
  scripts=(
    script1 script2 script3 script4 script5
  )

  total_scripts=${#scripts[*]}

  for ((i = 0; i < total_scripts; i++)); do
    declare -A i_=(
    ['comments']=$(grep -c '#' "${scripts[$i]}")
    ['total_lines']=$(wc -l < "${scripts[$i]}")
    ['if_commands_total']=$(grep -Fc 'if ' "${scripts[$i]}")
  )
    for ((j = i + 1 ; j < total_scripts; j++)); do
        declare -A j_=(
        ['comments']="$(grep -c '#' "${scripts[$j]}")"
        ['total_lines']="$(wc -l < "${scripts[$j]}")"
        ['if_commands_total']="$(grep -Fc 'if ' "${scripts[$j]}")"
      )
      printf '%s ' "The ${scripts[$i]} has ${i_[total_lines]} lines"
      printf 'and %s\n' "The ${scripts[$j]} has ${j_[total_lines]} lines"
      printf '%s ' "The ${scripts[$i]} has ${i_[comments]} comments"
      printf 'and %s\n' "The ${scripts[$j]} has ${j_[comments]} comments"
      printf '%s ' "The ${scripts[$i]} has ${i_[if_commands_total]} if commands"
      printf 'and %s\n' "The ${scripts[$j]} has ${j_[if_commands_total]} if commands"
      done
  unset i_ j_ 'scripts[i]'
  scripts=("${scripts[@]}")
  total_scripts=${#scripts[*]}
  done
}

for item in lines comments if; do
  funct | grep "$item"
  echo
done
```

- Requires bash4+ because of associative array.

Comment: It works perfect for 5 scripts, but the problem is that my array have more than 5 scripts. My array can have an undetermined number of scripts because this arrays come from a for loop that track trough multiple directories searching for scripts. I am trying to make this code useful for an array with an undetermined number of scripts but so far I have not achieve anything, any idea?

Comment: just save the files in a bash array structure, then you should be good,  I just gave an example on how to do it from an array.

Comment: `my_array=(); for  files in ...; do my_array+=("$files"); done`  now `"${my_array[@]}"` has all your files, of course adapt your for loop to that syntax.

Comment: Yes, I have my scripts in an array in the way you have said. For example, my array has now 6 scripts.

Comment: And the output does not compare script2-script3, script2-script4, script2-script5, script2-script6, and some other comparisons. It only works when my array has 5 scripts, and my intention is to use the code with an array with an undetermined numer of scripts. So I am looking for how to use properly this code with an array with more than 5 scripts.

Comment: Okey, I have just achieved it, thanks for your help.